# Creating an unofficial Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: discussion, api, legal, android

I am trying to create an unofficial Stack Exchange Android app and I have a few questions regarding that.

1. Is it permitted to create Stack Exchange's unofficial Android app using Stack Exchange APIs?
2. What would be a good name for it or will just "Stack Exchange - Unofficial" do?

Comment: If it's unofficial, you might not be able to use the name at all. Or even use the app in the first place. Somehow, I doubt it's the same as publishing an unauthorized biography. (Although an unauthorized biography is likely to involve some legal hurdles.)

Comment: Hi @JasonBassford, I don't know about name but i think it's ok to create an app after all stackexchange provides API. If not what's the use of them ?

Comment: App Overflow? (meh, minimum comment length requirement)

Comment: The big pain point for many users is just the lack of notifications. It is not particularly ambitious but stack notifications would be appreciated, even if it just shows us notifications at a glance and sends us over to the site proper 

Comment: @JourneymanGeek indeed. If iOS 14 proves to be the final nail in the coffin for the iOS app (because the answers don't seem to display), I'll probably write a service which monitors the websocket for inbox notifications, and sends push notifications to an app which isn't much more than a wrapper for the responsive website.

Comment: I've been developing an Stack Exchange app as a personal project to learn Jetpack Compose. I am keeping it simple since my idea is just learn, but if you are interested, we could extend it's functionality to actually be a community app: https://github.com/vitor-ramos/LiveQuestions

Comment: I ended up creating a new app exacly how @JourneymanGeek described: https://stackapps.com/questions/8774/stack-updates-mobile-app-for-receiving-push-notifications

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. It is allowed to create an Android app; in fact, many people have [tried](https://stackapps.com/search?tab=relevance&q=android) already. I'm not sure if there are any up to date ones, at one point they were superseded by the official one. Now that the official one has been abandoned, this could be the moment to launch a community-maintained one.

2. You cannot use the entire name "Stack Exchange", since it's protected, but either word is OK. See the [Trademark Guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance):

> - **Do** name your application with something unique. Including one of the terms, "Stack" or "Exchange" or "Overflow" in your product name is generally okay.
> - **Do not** use our name in the name of your product.

What a *good* name is, is primarily opinion based – we can't answer that, you have to come up with your own.

Comment: I am thinking of "QA Overflow" and already working on it.

Comment: It'll be a stack overflow client not stack exchange.